# Need to load huge dataset (32 Million) into table using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a huge dataset to return in SQL Server( about 32 million rows) This is implemented in view and source code is as follows :

```
SELECT Idenitifier = ISNULL(mle.MIdeer, mle.Ider) + em.MemberId,
       EffectiveDate = ISNULL(em.EffectiveDate, 
                                (SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveDate
                                 FROM   c
                                 WHERE  SourceType = em.SourceType
                                    AND GroupNumber = em.GroupNumber
                                    AND ISNULL(GroupDivision, '') = 
                                        ISNULL(em.GroupDivision, '')))
FROM   a em
       JOIN b mle
         ON mle.Identifier = em.GroupNumber + ISNULL('-' + em.GroupDivision, '')

            -- Filter invalid legal entities
            AND ISNULL(mle.Filter, 0) = 0

       --- Gets a resultset of 531798 rows 

       CROSS JOIN -- this returns 63 rows , so  
       -- I am presuming 531798*63 rows here.
       (SELECT *
        FROM   map
        WHERE  domaintype = 'MC')b;
```

I need to load this dataset using SSIS into a table. After 16 million rows, I am getting a system.out of memory exception in sql server when I am giving a `select * from <<view>>`. How to load this dataset in table using SSIS,avoiding this exception..

What other better methods to do this query efficiently as it takes more than 30 mins to run?

Comment: The out of memory exception, is that being reported from SSMS when you just run the query?

Comment: Is the query above being used in SSIS as the data source?  Also, why do you need to use SSIS?

Comment: Given that your error message is coming from SSMS and not SSIS, I think you have a non issue, despite your upvotes. While the team certainly tuned for performance, the SSIS team was able to load [1TB in 30 minutes on 6 year old hardware](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx). 30M rows is nothing.

Comment: Hugh? Oh my, 321 million is small. This is 2013. I run 9 billion rows on 5 year old hardware. Obviously I do not try to load them all into a SSMS result at once.

Comment: That query looks like it could do with optimization though. Wrapping everything in `ISNULL` makes it unsargable and the correlated `TOP 1` for 32 million rows may well be a problem.

Comment: It should be noted of course that @AaronBertrand 's dog is named "Mr. Peabody". :-)

Comment: My hardware is 36 years old and always performs in under 10 seconds

Comment: You've got a correlated subquery in the columns, a cross join and  joins and filters using non sargable  expressions. This query is ripe for optimisation. Which version of SQL Server are you on? If possible you might consider loading the cross join part of it on the target side if you have the luxury of staging tables.

Comment: Yes, the good part of it is that we do have a staging table in the destination ,but how do I incorporate the cross join concept in there ?If I am handling cross join in my target table it would look like select * from staging3.table cross join (select * from staging2.map where domaintype ='MC').I need to put this in SSIS component and I am pretty sure this query cannot be handled in SSIS owing to multiple connection managers in one query? any thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still thinking through this, but you might need to separate the `CROSS JOIN`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT  ISNULL(mle.MIdeer, mle.Ider) + em.MemberId AS Idenitifier
                      , ISNULL(em.EffectiveDate,
                               ( SELECT TOP 1
                                        EffectiveDate
                                 FROM   c
                                 WHERE  SourceType = em.SourceType
                                        AND GroupNumber = em.GroupNumber
                                        AND ISNULL(GroupDivision, '') = ISNULL(em.GroupDivision,
                                                                              '')
                               )) AS EffectiveDate
                FROM    a em
                JOIN    b mle ON mle.Identifier = em.GroupNumber + ISNULL('-'+ em.GroupDivision,'')
                            AND ISNULL(mle.Filter, 0) = 0)
SELECT *
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT *
             FROM   map
             WHERE  domaintype = 'MC') b;
```

Comment: How is this query better than the query I posted other than code manageability? Could you pls justify...

Comment: @user3277506 In limited testing this was faster the cross join in the same query, I only had time to test a little, at very few records it was identical, but when I cranked up the record counts it altered the query plan and performed better.  Nothing beyond that, did it give you the same memory error?

Comment: Well it did better this time but after loading 16 Million rows , it throws up the memory error. You think anything related to rendering data in memory,may be clearing up temp folder or so..shd resolve?